# Laravel 7 error 150 foreign keys - Xampp / wamp

Tags: laravel, xampp, wamp

resulta que siempre trabajé con Wamp sin ningún problema, ahora me mudé a Xampp y en laravel creo las migraciones de la misma forma pero al momento de hacer php artisan migrate, me arroja:

error: 150 "foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Hice una prueba con las mismas migraciones de un proyecto, y en Wamp funciona como siempre y con Xampp arroja siempre ese error.
Leí que podria ser problema del orden en que se crean las tablas, aún asi no funciona. No sé que puede ser ya.

Mis migraciones:

Tabla Productos

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('id_categoria');
            $table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('productos');
    }
}
```

Tabla Categorias:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categorias');
    }
}
```

El error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `mercadopago`.`productos` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `productos` add constraint `productos_id_categoria_foreign` foreign key (`id_categoria`) references `categorias` (`id`))
```

[image: Aqui pueden ver que con xampp me arroja ese error]

[image: El orden de mis migraciones]

Comment: Necesitamos mas datos para poder ayudar, recomiendo leas [ask] y agregues un [mcve]

Comment: Perfecto!, acabo de agregar mas detalles

Comment: Los tipos de datos para la llave foránea no empatan, cambia `integer` por `unsignedBigInteger` donde declaras la llave foránea y ya debería funcionar

Comment: Funcionó!, lo raro es que deba cambiarlo usando xampp y con wamp no me trae problemas.